# How to add an Imageview near to a TextView dynamically from an existing layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have `textview` with `imageview`. Now textview will be generated dynamically. But how to add `imageview` along with that?

> xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

      <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_rl_block4_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/growth_rl_block_title_table"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_block4_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/growth_rl_block_title_table"
                            android:background="@drawable/dot_green" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_block4_body1_1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/growth_not1" />
                    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

In MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

 String[] word = {"This is text1.So it should be single line", "This is text2", "This is text3"};

TextView broadcastMessage;
ImageView greenDot;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

broadcastMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_block4_body1_1);
 greenDot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_block4_1);
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            broadcastMessage.append(word[i]);
            broadcastMessage.append("\n");
        }
        }
```

If you see the xml, there is an `imageview` too. So now `textview` is generated dynamically but the `imageview` is not proper corresponding to `textview`. `Imageview` will be in left side and corresponding near to that is `TextView`. But the dot is missing near to the textview when generating dynamically from `xml`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by adding a compound drawable (left, top, right, bottom) as follows:

```
broadcastMessage.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley ), null, null, null);
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            broadcastMessage.append(word[i]);
            broadcastMessage.append("\n");
            broadcastMessage.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.dot_green ), null, null, null);
        }